# Navigating between pages in flutter web app with a persistent side menu and Top bar

Tags: flutter, dashboard

My Web app(Attendance Management System) contains a dashboard which opens after login. The dashboard contains some data on the right side, a menubar on the left side and a header container on the top. When a user clicks on each menu item, that relevant page should open (like employee page, department page etc.) on the right side of the dashboard, but keeping the left menu and top bar intact. How should I achieve this? By containers or with the help of any other methods or widgets?

This is going to be my first Flutter web app (I have developed mobile applications). It will be the backend application for the attendance app developed in Flutter. Is it recommended to use a responsive layout in such projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution base could be something like this, if I understood your question correctly.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String selectedSidebarItem = 'Home';

  void onSidebarItemSelected(String item) {
    setState(() {
      selectedSidebarItem = item;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Fixed Sidebar Example'),
      ),
      body: Row(
        children: [
          // Sidebar
          Container(
            width: 200,
            child: Drawer(
              child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                children: [
                  DrawerHeader(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      'Sidebar',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 24,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Home'),
                    onTap: () => onSidebarItemSelected('Home'),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Settings'),
                    onTap: () => onSidebarItemSelected('Settings'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          // Content
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Selected Sidebar Item:',
                  ),
                  Text(
                    selectedSidebarItem,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

With Get lib

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    GetMaterialApp(
      initialBinding: BindingsBuilder(() {
        Get.put(MyController());
      }),
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyController extends GetxController {
  var selectedSidebarItem = 'Home'.obs;

  void updateSelectedSidebarItem(String item) {
    selectedSidebarItem.value = item;
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Fixed Sidebar Example'),
      ),
      body: Row(
        children: [
          // Sidebar
          Container(
            width: 200,
            child: Drawer(
              child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                children: [
                  DrawerHeader(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      'Sidebar',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 24,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Home'),
                    onTap: () {
                      Get.find<MyController>().updateSelectedSidebarItem('Home');
                      Get.toNamed('/Home');
                    },
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Settings'),
                    onTap: () {
                      Get.find<MyController>().updateSelectedSidebarItem('Settings');
                      Get.toNamed('/Settings');
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          // Content
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Selected Sidebar Item:',
                  ),
                  // Use Obx to listen for changes in selectedSidebarItem
                  Obx(() => Text(
                    Get.find<MyController>().selectedSidebarItem.value,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  )),
                  // Display content based on selectedSidebarItem
                  if (Get.find<MyController>().selectedSidebarItem.value == 'Home')
                    HomeContent()
                  else if (Get.find<MyController>().selectedSidebarItem.value == 'Settings')
                    SettingsContent(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeContent extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('Home Page Content');
  }
}

class SettingsContent extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('Settings Page Content');
  }
}
```

Comment: I will try the above and update.

Comment: I tried the above code and it's working. In Expanded Widget, I made the below change and it's giving error. The argument type 'Future<dynamic>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'. Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: (selectedSidebarItem == 'Home')
                        ? Get.toNamed(RoutesClass.employeePage)
                        : Get.toNamed(RoutesClass.employeePage),
                  )

Comment: Ok, so you are using GetX. Let me check out the lib before answering.

Comment: In the meantime I asked my friend @Chatty Gepete and he produced some nice code.
I extended the answer.

Comment: By the way, why do you insist on using navigation and routes, when you actually stay in the same widget, I don't see the reason,is there some special feature that forces you to want to solve the problem this way?

Comment: There is no particular reason. I wanted to know how it is normally being done or if is there any best practice to follow. When I click side menu items, it should open the corresponding page on the right side of the dashboard. Each of those pages will have CRUD functionalities. That is what I wanted.

Comment: Which State Management is better in Flutter Web?

Comment: I would not think about opening a page in a page in your case. The widget structure kind of pushes you into solving this on a single page. As for which is better I don't know. Flutter team recommends using the bloc pattern and most of my experience is with provider. On the other hand, the description of GetX promises to solve the problem in a reactive, DI driven way and claim they are even more performant. It's up to you to choose.